# Error cloning remote repo to kie workbench

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, kie-server, drools-kie-server, drools-kie-workbench

I'm new with drools and especially with the kie-server standalone. I'm working on a POC for my project and I'm having some issues trying to deploy an artifact from a remote repository. I created a remote repository (as a maven artifact) and one Project inside it. 
I cloned this repo in my local workbench but I can not open any java or drl file because I get an error like **"Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: Editor model couldn't be loaded from path: default://master@remoteRuleRepo/CartPromoFact/src/main/java/demo/cartpromofact/User.java."**
Also I can not **"Build & Deploy"** this project, and I don't get any error on console.

Thanks

Comment: Put any details you need from external URLs into the body of the question. External links will make questions eventually less useful for others. Try to make the question stand-alone. What are you trying to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get. Edit the question to update it with these details.

Comment: You may encounter similar issue of POJO class is not in kie-workbench format. Have you added annotation '   @org.kie.api.definition.type.Label("")' to each field ?

Answer (score 0):

As this is one of the top hits for the same error I faced: I got this error message when I deployed the workbench to a container that did not have internet access. Both workbench and kie server need to be able to access the internet to download things.